# How can I disable the FF warning everytime in the pdf browser?

Tags: firefox, pdf

[image]

How can I disable this from showing up whenever I open a pdf?

Comment: This is considered to be a usability bug by many: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=767455.

Comment: If you already have an alternate PDF viewer plugin for Firefox, you can completely disable the internal pdf.js viewer by going to **about:config** and setting **pdfjs.disabled** to *true*.